# Backup jobs in ARCServe fail trying to back up deleted files and directories. How can fix this?

Tags: backup

I am using ARCServe r12 SP2. Our daily backup jobs are failing while trying to back up files and directories on a remote server that have been deleted. How can I fix this?

Comment: BackupExec will occasionally exhibit this behavior as well. Refreshing your backup selection list may resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with old arcserve version, it make a difference if you select a path to get all under (like c:\ all sub dir), than just selecting some under a root (like d:\group\share1, d:\group\share2, etc..)

In that case if share1\ is deleted then it throw out a error.

nb. From the arcserve version I was using I had to click two time on the [+] sign to get all under correctly.